# Filtering an array of object with priorities

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I'm trying to filter and array of people and get the results in a specific order. Which mean when user enter someString, I want to present first the people that that their name match that someString, and then start with that someString and after that any name that contain that some string.
Any way I can do it with Array "Filter" or I must preform another manual sort after that?

Here's my filtering code:

```
self.filteredNames = self.names.filter({$0.name.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(text!) | $0.name.lowercaseString.containsString(text!) | $0.allEmails.lowercaseString.containsString(text!.lowercaseString) | $0.allNumbers.lowercaseString.containsString(text!.lowercaseString)})
```

Comment: Your filtering code doesn't match your description of your problem. It looks like you are filtering on different fields rather than less specific requirements on the same field.

Comment: actually, both . the results should be as ordered  : names that match the string,names that start with that string, names that contain that string, email that contain that string, phone numbers that contain that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` can only remove items from a collection. It can't do any ordering operations for you.

You probably want to solve this using a single pass of the array so it will perform decently. Don't use filter and instead do something basic like this:

```
var query = "test"

let allStrings = ["another test", "test", "testing", "random"]

var matchStrings = [String]()
var prefixStrings = [String]()
var containsStrings = [String]()

for str in allStrings {

    if query == str {
        matchStrings.append(str)
    } else if str.hasPrefix(query) {
        prefixStrings.append(str)
    } else if str.containsString(query) {
        containsStrings.append(str)
    }
}

let results = matchStrings + prefixStrings + containsStrings
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort`:

```
func sortingFunction(obj1: YourClass, _ obj2: YourClass) -> Bool {
    return (str1.name.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(text!) && !obj2.name.lowercaseString.hasPrefix(text!)) ||
        (obj1.name.lowercaseString.containsString(text!) && !obj2.name.lowercaseString.containsString(text!)) ||
        (obj1.allEmails.lowercaseString.containsString(text!) && !obj2.allEmails.lowercaseString.containsString(text!)) &&
        (obj1.allNumbers.lowercaseString.containsString(text!) && !obj2.allNumbers.lowercaseString.containsString(text!))
}

self.filteredNames = self.names.sort(sortingFunction)
```

Comment: You'll still need an operation to remove any elements that don't match the query at all though right?

Comment: right, this will only sort the element and not remove any at all, your answer is suitable for that

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't match your problem description. I'm gonna go with what you described since your code doesn't do what you want anyway.

You can score each match and sort by the matching score:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
}

let names = [
    Person(name: "John Smith"),
    Person(name: "Alan Johnson"),
    Person(name: "Jane Doe"),
    Person(name: "John")
]

let searchText = "John".lowercaseString // take this from you search box

let filteredNames = names.flatMap { p -> (Person, Int)? in
    var score = 0
    let name = p.name.lowercaseString

    if name == searchText {
        score += 3
    } else if name.hasPrefix(searchText) {
        score += 2
    } else if name.containsString(searchText) {
        score += 1  
    }

    return score == 0 ? nil : (p, score)
}.sort { $0.1 > $1.1 }
 .map { $0.0 }

print(filteredNames) // John, John Smith, Alan Johnson
```

Here what it does:

- `flatMap` acts as a `map` and a `filter` at the same time. Each person is assigned a matching score based on your criteria. If the matching score is 0, we return `nil` so `flatMap` excludes it.
- `sort` sort the result by the matching score
- `map` remove the matching score so the final array only contains the `Person`

You can extend this to email, phone numbers, etc. Just play around the scoring mechanism.

Comment: This approach will require multiple iterations over the collection, (although at least the subsequent `sort` and `map` will be over a subset of the collection). For a large collection, particularly where there are a lot of  'hits', a single `for` loop will probably perform better right?

Comment: Donald Knuth: "premature optimization is the root of all evils". Performance depends on a lot of factors: (a) for you to really see a difference, there needs to be hundreds of thousand of items in array; (b) your `for` loop similarly iterate though it multiple times; (c) if you change `Person` from `struct` to `class` it will be a lot faster since it only needs to copy the pointer address, not the whole struct. Just use whatever make the most sense to you, then benchmark and optimize performance

Comment: In relation to (b), where are the multiple iterations happening?

Comment: Your final line. When you add multiple arrays together, you need to iterate through them to build the resulting array

Comment: Yeah, - the concatenation may have a similar cost to the additional iterations (for all I know).  Also, for a large number of different 'scoring' operations your solution is quite elegant compared to creating multiple arrays